# How to send string with special character in URL search string?

Tags: string, curl

I want to create HTTP request using CURL. Here I want to send query string with special characters. How can send following string in **source** key?

"#include int main(){ return 0; }"

I have code like below, but it's not working

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"problemCode": "SE0034", "compilerId": 11, "source": "#include<stdio.h> int main(){ return 0; }"}' "http://92161595.problems.sphere-engine.com/api/v3/submissions?access_token=12345678dsw21"
```

I don't know what was wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error with the sample you provided. Running that exact curl command returned with `{"message":"Unauthorized","data":[]}`.

I would recommend verifying you have the right access token and that you are escaping any double quotes if you are dynamically generating the `source` value

Comment: I have changed the original access token before post the question.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the solution, the solution for above problem is we need to encode the string to remove the unsupported characters before create HTTP request.

Ex)

I have changed the string **"#include int main(){ return 0; }"** into **"%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E+int+main%28%29%7B+return+0%3B+%7D"**. Now it's working fine.